# External monitor loses video starting at top and gradually moving down

Tags: laptop, video, vpn, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a user that has a Dell Latitude 7420 and uses an external monitor with it both at home and in the office.  The complaint is that the external screen will gradually lose the video a chunk at a time over a seemingly random period of time. First the top inch or so will disappear, then maybe another inch and so on till the whole screen is black except for the taskbar at the bottom.  It's full lines across, not like awkward chunks. It happens both in office and at home and on totally different equipment.  Some days it doesn't happen much, but others it happens enough to be detrimental to her productivity.  From what I'm told, the issue resolves temporarily by simply unplugging and reconnecting the HDMI cable, though she also references doing frequent restarts to fix it.

Here's what we've tried:

- She's had 3 different laptops and between those, one (her original) had it's HDMI output replaced and was re-imaged with a fresh Windows 10 image.
- She uses different monitors, both in office and at home.
- She's tried a USB-C multiport adapter and used the VGA and HDMI on it to connect her home monitor.
- She's used different Dell docking stations to connect the various laptops.
- We've ensured she's not using some odd combination of scaling and resolution that might cause it.

She has all the same equipment and software installed on the laptop as the other 40+ people in her department and has no rights to install other software.  No matter what we've tried so far, the issue only happens to her and on all combinations of equipment.

I'm at a total loss.  The only common thread seems to be her and the software installed, which is again, the same software as everyone else and includes mainly MS Office365 Pro Plus, Adobe Acrobat Reader and a VPN software we have to use for the work we do with the client she's assigned to.  Other than that, there really isn't much else that gets installed outside of the standard image on everyone else's computer. All her work is done via a web application and those few pieces of software.